# Angular2/material 2: md-input-container label is not resetting float when value is changed programmatically

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I'm having an issue using @angular/material's `md-input-containers` and reactive forms module.

I am making a login form with three `md-inputs` that are all tied to values using the `FormBuilder`'s `FormGroup`. Everything there works fine.

My problem is that on the `ngSubmit` function, I am having the form reset if the credentials entered are invalid. Using the `.reset()` method of the `FormGroup` will reset the values to default, but the floating labels in the `md-input-containers` are not resetting to their original place, as they should be on an empty field. I am guessing the Material Design directives are looking for a blur event to update this but I can't tell, and I don't know how to force that to happen.

Here's the `ngSubmit` function:

```
  submitForm(username: string, password: string, companyID: any):void {

    this.userService.login(username, password, companyId)
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['main']);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.loginForm.reset();
      })
    }
```

and upon the `this.loginForm.reset()` being called, the forms will reset to default (empty strings), but the labels will still float:

[Labels still float. I reset Company ID for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeOPU.png)

Any idea on how to fix this? I don't really want to invoke an `ElementRef`, though I have already tried doing so to force a blur and that didn't solve it.

Comment: If this is still a problem for anyone, I'd recommend making a plunker and submitting an issue on https://github.com/angular/material2

Answer (score 0):

Try using md-input control instead of input wrapped in md-input-container.
It worked for me.